# Google CMP/GDPR message don't show up

Tags: ads, adsense, cmp, gdprconsentform, cookieconsent

Adsense now requires a consent message regarding GDPR. I have set up and published the message directly in Adsense. Unfortunately, the message does not appear on the site and thus no ads. For debugging purposes, I have removed all Google codes from the page and left only one single snippet - unfortunately without success. Does the page need to contain some other specific code or am I missing something?

My site: Gamebazar.cz

More info: When i add parameter "always show (Displays the published message. Ignores region.)" - [www.gamebazar.cz/?fc=alwaysshow](http://www.gamebazar.cz/?fc=alwaysshow) - then  message appear, so, code must work. What am i missing? Site and hosting are in EU, i am (and users are) accessing it from EU, but message don't appear.

Thank you for any tips

I tried to access it from different machines, mobiles etc... nothing works. I want to message appear on my site and by able to show ads.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and for me it was the header `Referrer-Policy` which was set to `cross-origin`. After I set it to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`, everything worked as it should.

You can find more information at https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/14660912?hl=en

Comment: HI, thanks for tip. I tried this, but unfortunately without success :(

Answer (score 0):

I am a Google AdSense expert. I checked your website. No CMP - does not meet TCF 2.2 rules. Remove the "cookiebot" script. Your "cookiebot" script overrides the CMP from AdSense and this causes an error.

Comment: Hi, I had to use the Cookiebot script because I was unable to get Google to work :(

Comment: Hi, But this script is not compatible with the EU.

Comment: Hi, i tried implementing Cookiebot script through Google tag manager. Would you kindly check if now is everything OK? Thank you.